# Visio Master Shape to update shape text based on shape data field

Tags: text, shapes, visio, shapesheet

I have a Visio (365) Master Shape I am creating for my work. I have a number of defined shape data fields, such as Type / Status / Display / Category etc... These are defined as defined as shape data and not as shape data set and can be accessed in formulas with the Prop.x notation.

I have selected the master shape for editing from the stencil, opened it for editing, selected the shape and then selected from the menu bar / ribbon 'Insert -> Field', and have tried to display shape text by inserting a field with a custom formula:

```
=IF(Prop.Display,IF(Prop.Type <> "",Prop.Type,""),"")
```

The shape data field 'Display' is Boolean with default set to TRUE. The field 'Type' is a delimited list / dropdown that initially starts out blank.

The objective is to have the user select a Type (when they know what it is), and the formula (in theory) should update the shape text to display that selection.

The problem is that when I test the shape and make changes to either the Type field or the Display field nothing happens - no text is ever displayed.

I'm sure that I am missing something simple here, but I cannot figure out what that is. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers

The Frog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

The formula to use is the following:

```
=IF(AND(Prop.Display,FORMULAEXISTS(Prop.Type)),Prop.Type,CHAR(32))
```

The combination of Prop.Display (boolean) being set to True, AND Prop.Type actually having something selected - tested with the FORMULAEXISTS function, creates a True / False scenario, where true provides the value of Prop.Type, and false provides a blank space - doesn't seem to like "" or CHAR(0) as a value so the single space character is the best I could do.

Cheers and many thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

The Frog

Answer (score 0):

I think this part of formula dont works: `if(Prop.Type <> "",Prop.Type,"")`.

For compare text strings use [STRSAME function](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-developer-client-docs/blob/main/docs/visio/strsame-function.md), with syntax: `STRSAME(Prop.Type,"")`.
For empty string you can use `LEN(Prop.Type)=0`

Comment: Thanks for having a crack at this. I think this is heading in the right direction. What I have managed to get working on the Master Shape (when editing it) is:

=IF(Prop.Display,IF(Prop.Type=0,"Undefined",Prop.Type),"")

When the shape is first dropped onto the page 'Undefined' is now displayed, but changing the Type to another selection from the list does not change the displayed text. Unfortunately LEN(Prop.Type) appears to do nothing with a defined list - or at least I cannot see it doing anything to cause change.

Comment: OK Bizarrely this formula seems to almost work:
    =IF(Prop.Display,IF(LEN(Prop.Type)>0,Prop.Type,""),"")
The only thing that is weird is that the state of Prop.Type not yet being selected (ie/ has no value) is not producing an empty string as proscribed in the formula, but rather the text "0.0000" - even when I put "Undefined" in the false position of the inner IF statement. Very odd.

Comment: For shape data properties, two conditions need to be checked: if no value has been entered and if a zero-length string has been entered. On the shapesheet, if no value has been entered, then the Prop.Formula cell has the value `No Formula`. `LEN()` for this cell returns 1, while a formula of "" returns 0. to detect an empty string in Prop.X use `OR(LEN(Prop.X)=0,NOT(FORMULAEXISTS(Prop.X))`. It's unwieldly, but the beast I have so far.